# Swift 2: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '()?' and 'Bool'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cocoaasyncsocket

After I updated Xcode 7 beta and convert my swift code to Swift 2, I got these two errors that I can't figure out..

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled
>
> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '()?' and 'Bool'

My code is here.

```
if self.socket?.connectToHost(host, onPort: port, viaInterface: interfaceName, withTimeout: 10) == true {
// connecting
} else {
// error
  let delay = 1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
  let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
  dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  self._connect()
  })
}
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Bool is yes / no... `if (!myBool) { ... }` or `if (myBool) { ... }`

Comment: For the record, you should avoid `== true`. It's redundant. Just use `if condition`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on how the CocoaAsyncSocket framework is used in Swift, the function `connectToHost:onPort:viaInterface:withTimeout:` does not have a return value. Instead it only throws. Therefore, the meaning of the error is that a `Void`, no return value, cannot be compared to a `Bool`.

Its declaration in Swift is:

```
func connectToHost(host: String!, onPort port: UInt16, viaInterface interface: String!, withTimeout timeout: NSTimeInterval) throws
```

This differs from its declaration when used with Objective-C where the declaration is:

```
- (BOOL)connectToHost:(NSString *)hostname onPort:(UInt16)port withTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout
```

As an aside, in Objective-C, you could handle a `nil` as if it were a boolean along with nonzero values being evaluated as `TRUE`, but those possibilities were removed from Swift because they are a common source of errors.

To handle the error requires the following form known as do-try-catch. Here is an example adjusted to your code:

```
do {
    try self.socket?.connectToHost(host, onPort: port, viaInterface: interfaceName, withTimeout: 10) 
    // connecting
} catch let error as NSError {
    // Handle the error here.
    let delay = 1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self._connect()
    })
}
```

Comment: Void cant be used as bool in any language

Comment: @Sulthan That's correct. I was thinking of the imprecision of the BOOL type in Objective-C but I was wrong about it applying to the Void type.

Comment: @DanielZhang Thank you. It's solved. As you mentioned, I need to change error handling method.